# Calling a module in routing module of Angular 8 with # or import

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I'm coding an App with Angular and implementing lazy loading I've found theses three way to do:

First one:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer-list',
      loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule) },
    { path: 'order-list',
      loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule) }
    ];
```

second one

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer-list',
      loadChildren: () => './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
    { path: 'order-list',
      loadChildren: () => './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
    ];
```

And last one

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'customer-list',
      loadChildren: () => CustomersModule
    { path: 'order-list',
      loadChildren: () => OrdersModule
    ];
```

Does Anyone know what is the difference ?  Thank you.